# How can one have smartphone/tablet -like GUI on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, raspberry-pi

I'm planning of developing an application which will run on a Raspberry Pi 2 equipped with a touch-screen, and it should have the look and feel of a smartphone/tablet application.

This means especially that the list views and other scrollable widgets should scroll via touch gestures, and not by clicking on narrow scroll-bars on their side. Also, a simulation of momentum (widget scrolls a little while longer, with gradually lower speed, if I scrolled it fast enough and let go of the screen) should also be applied to all scrollable items.

I would prefer to develop in C++, and as I'm used to Qt, it would be preferable as well.

However, the Qt widgets are designed with a PC in mind, so they don't scroll with hand gestures and they have no simulation of momentum.

Of course, I could derive my own classes from the Qt classes and implement these features myself, but it would be much simpler if such GUI classes already existed.

Comment: You should take a look at QML. It is Qt too, so it is just as awesome! I'm no expert on it, but I've played a bit with touch and animations on it and I was very pleased with the speed and quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html) for build GUI if you want to look like mobile. [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html) and [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html) you have how to integrate QML with C++ objects, so you can implement your logic by C++. In QML you can use TableView which can be scroll via touch the table.